# How can you use negative margin when positioning a fixed element?

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to position an element with position:fixed; within an expanding(liquid) element.

I want the element to stay to the right no matter how wide the display gets.

box1 is inside box2

box2 is the center column and is expandable with browser size

box1 is fixed and should float above the right edge of box2(center column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
.box1 {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    margin-right:-20px;
}
```

Comment: ! A slight modification of this worked. I never use simply right/left styles, I guess because I never use fixed positioning and margins usually work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve this effect by making box2 `position:relative;`, and then setting box1 to `position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;`... if I understand you correctly.

Comment: box1 actually needs to stay position:fixed; but you were spot on with the use of right:0;

Answer (score 3):

As best I can tell from your query:

```
element {
  float:right;
  margin-left:x;
  z-index:10;
}
box2 {
  width:80%;
  z-index:-10;
}
box1 {
 margin-left:20%;
 z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably just want to float-right.